# Geometry questions (high school)

Tags: geometry

I did my work but I need someone to check my answers and help me with another.

1. A ship leaves port at noon and has a bearing of $\text{S} 29^{\circ} \text{W}$. The ship sails at $20 \text{ knots}$. How many nautical miles $\text{S}$ and how many nautical miles $\text{W}$ will the ship have traveled by 6:00 PM? I said $\langle 120 \cos(29^\circ), 120 \sin(29^\circ) \rangle$
2. (Spherical Geometry) Draw triangles with 1 right angle, 2 right angles and 3 right angles respectively.

My issue here is that I don't know how it's possible to draw a spherical triangle with 2 right angles.

Comment: For a spherical triangle with two right angles, put two vertices on equator and one at pole.

Comment: Thanks I see the picture that you described

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1 the answer is correct with position vector coordinates as 
(-120cos(29 degrees)i^, -120sin(29 degrees)j^) [north as +ve Y]

2 These images may hel
http://euler.slu.edu/escher/upload/thumb/5/5d/Sphere-triangle909045.png/180px-Sphere-triangle909045.png

http://www.math.cornell.edu/~mec/tripleright.jpg